# Pass Class Object to MultiPart Entity in android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, multipartentity

I have to work on an application where i need to send the class object as Parameter using Multipart Entity along with a file. I have checked that the Multipart addpart method doesn't accept an Object to post to Web Api.Below is the Code i have tried. Any Suggestions on how to pass the object would be great.

```
        HttpPost post = BaseActivity.getHttpPost("MyURL");          

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,"",Charset.defaultCharset());

        try {
            ServiceJobFileModel sjfm = new ServiceJobFileModel();

            sjfm.setFileExtension(myfileextension);
            sjfm.setCapturedDate(captdate);
            sjfm.setFileName("/pathtofile/filename.extension");

            File f = new File(sjmf.getFileName());

            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(f));
            entity.addPart("serviceJobFileModel", sjfm); // Compiler Error

            post.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            post.setEntity(entity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.v("encoding exception","E::: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Web Api is developed in Dotnet which is why the windows mobile app has sent the parameters as

```
 var parameters = new ServiceJobFileModel()
            {
                FileExtension = serviceJobFileModel.FileExtension,
                CapturedDate = serviceJobFileModel.CapturedDate,                     
                ServiceJobNumber = serviceJobFileModel.ServiceJobNumber
            };

content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
content.Add(new ObjectContent<ServiceJobFileModel>(parameters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()), "serviceJobFileModel");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you should **serialize** your object in a text format like **JSON** or **XML** and then use a `StringBody` to send it.